# FTP in Windows Explorer's date modified timestamp is off by 5 hours

Tags: ftp, windows-explorer, date-modified

We are using Serv-U as our FTP server on Windows Server 2008 R2.

When I use windows explorer on a Windows 7 desktop to connect to the ftp site the Date Modified timestamp is off by exactly 5 hours...But if I use other ftp clients(Firefox and Filezilla) I get the correct timestamps.

The time on the desktop and server are correct and in the same timezone (central).

Comment: Does your timezone happen to be by 5 hours off of UTC?

Comment: According to Wikipedia: Daylight saving time (DST) is in effect in much of Central time zones between mid-March and early November. The modified time is called Central Daylight Time (CDT) and is UTC−5.  So yes.  Is this a Windows bug then?

Comment: If you place the file into the directory using a non-ftp copy (within Windows) do you get different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is the FTP clients setting the time on the file without regard to the time zone.  There are several old links discussing this.

http://help.globalscape.com/help/cuteftplite8/conserve_local_file_time.htm

http://www.gpsoft.com.au/help/opus9/default.htm?turl=WordDocuments%2Fenhancedtimezonesandremotedatestamps.htm

http://rhinosoft.com/Knowledgebase/kbarticle.asp?prod=rs&RefNo=1058